# How do you calculate the module of a high raised number?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I need some help solving this.

Find $3^{336549354297854} (mod 28)$

I don't really understand how to solve this type of problem. can anyone explain?

Comment: write the problem properly.What is $3^{(336549354297854)} mod 28$ congruent to?Please mention that.

Comment: That huge exponent, with a $2$ ar the end instead of $4$, is divisible by $3$ (look at the digit sum mod $3$).

Comment: Hint: $3^3=27\equiv-1\pmod{28}$ so $3^6\equiv1\pmod{28}$.

Comment: It is called the residue, not the module. The residue of  9 ,modulo 7, is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking for a pattern:

$3^0 \equiv 1 \pmod{28}$

$3^1 \equiv 3 \pmod{28}$

$3^2 \equiv 9 \pmod{28}$

$3^3 \equiv 27 \pmod{28}$

$3^4 \equiv 25 \pmod{28}$

$3^5 \equiv 19 \pmod{28}$

$3^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{28}$

$3^7 \equiv 3 \pmod{28}$

$3^8 \equiv 9 \pmod{28}$

So every $6^{th}$ value is the same. Your power can be written as:

$336549354297854=56091559049642\times6+\color{red}{2}$

So it will be the $3^2$=9.